# How did Malcom Young tame the feedback?

Tags: electric-guitar

I realise that Malcolm Young played a fair amount of solid-body Gretch guitars but for a certain amount of songs he played hollow-bodied Gretsch's as well. How did he not succumb to unruly feedback? At the volumes, ACDC played at and with all that gain I'm not sure how exactly he ever got a reasonable tone with such a guitar in such an environment?

Comment: Using a P.A. to send the sound out to the audience, the sound level on stage doesn't need to be that high that feedback is created. If it is, he'd do like the rest of us, and mute anything likely to feed back, using either/both hands.

Comment: You might be surprised how little gain is needed to get the tone he gets.

Comment: Carefully  :-)   is how

Comment: All I.know is eye contact with my amp is enough to have my acoustic feedback.

Comment: @NeilMeyer  as ***someone**** famously said,  "you're holding it wrong" .   Point that speaker (not amp) away from you.

Answer (score 3):

He might have put socks into the cavity. He did the same with a guitar that had empty pickup sockets.

"Malcolm Young's iconic 1963 Gretsch Jet Firebird guitar was originally red, given to him by AC/DC's early producer Harry Vanda. The guitar had the neck and middle pickups removed. Young later removed the red paint and, for a while, placed his socks in the pickup cavity to stop feedback"

https://www.musicradar.com/news/guitars/13-idiotic-ac-dc-facts-179026
(#3)